# If multiple rows have the same Name value, return the one with the highest ID value

Tags: sql-server

```
ID  Name    Address Birthdate

1   Steven  NULL    1982-01-23 

2   Andrew  2 Katherine St  1979-10-06

3   Andrew  81 South Rd NULL
```

In the above table if i enter Andrew in textbox i want to get data with Id no=3 . How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

For all unique names:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID, Name, Address, Birthdate,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC)
  FROM dbo.tablename
)
SELECT ID, Name, Address, Birthdate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

For just one:

```
SELECT TOP (1) ID, Name, Address, Birthdate
  FROM dbo.tablename
  WHERE Name = 'Andrew'
  ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @name varchar(100) = 'Andrew'

select top 1 *
from MyTable
where Name = @name
order by ID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that the table name is 'my_table'.
Try this:

```
SELECT max(ID) FROM my_table WHERE Name = 'Andrew'
```

More about the max function [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php).

Comment: And if the OP wants the name, address, birthdate etc. in addition to just the ID?

Comment: You're right. I read that he only wanted to obtain the highest ID, my bad. :) In that case, I'd go with your answer.